# SwiftUI - Spotify Auth Webview not loading in build but works in preview

Tags: swiftui

I have a problem where my webView doesn't load on build but in preview it works as it should. What I mean by not loading is that the webView is just white.

What I first thought was that the simulated iphones network settings made it so it didn't allow URLRequests for some reason but I disputed this quickly when I temporarily changed the url to "https://google.com" and it loaded as it should.

Here is my code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  spotifystats
//
//  Created by bappo on 2021-08-15.
//

import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SpotifyConstants {
    static let CLIENT_ID = "***************"
    static let SESSION_KEY = "spotifySessionKey"
    static let REDIRECT_URI = "spotifystats://"
    static let SCOPE = "user-read-email"
}

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let request: URLRequest
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLogginIn = false
    let authURLFull = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=" + SpotifyConstants.CLIENT_ID + "&scope=" + SpotifyConstants.SCOPE + "&redirect_uri=" + SpotifyConstants.REDIRECT_URI + "&show_dialog=false"
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Spotify Login") {
            isLogginIn = true
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.green)
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .sheet(isPresented: $isLogginIn) {
            WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: authURLFull)! ))
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        RequestForCallbackURL(request: navigationAction.request)
    }

    func RequestForCallbackURL(request: URLRequest) {
        let requestURLString = (request.url?.absoluteString)! as String
        print(requestURLString)
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: you code works well for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. 
Tested on macOS 12 and iPhone/iPad ios15.

Comment: are you just running the preview or are you building?

Comment: tested on real devices. preview is often "broken" for me, I never use it for real tests.